# How to make a progress bar on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I need to make a delivery progress bar on sheets like the one on DoubleClick for Publishers. 
I want the bar to show the percentage of delivery of a campaign according to its start and end date. Example:

[image: Google DFP progress bar]

*The progress is calculated as the percentage of impression goal delivered divided by the percentage of time elapsed:
progress = (% of impression goal delivered) / (% of time elapsed)
Delivery progress assumes an even distribution of impressions.*

*For example, a line item that has delivered 50% of its impression goal 50% of the way through the campaign has a progress of 100%. However, a line item that’s delivered 50% of its impression goal at the end of day 3 of a 4-day-long campaign would have a progress of:
50 / 75 = 66%*

On top of that I need the progress bar to show where in the campaign I am currently (vertical grey line in the photo).

Answer (score 30):

When I used teocrasto's formula, I got error, I probably should have changed something, but the following formula worked well for me.

```
=SPARKLINE(20,{"charttype","bar";"max",100})
```

In this example the progress bar is 20% filled. So change the number 100 to your "full" amount and 20 to whatever you want the bar to be filled. You can use cells instead of those number.

If you want to change the **color** of the "main" bar use this

```
=SPARKLINE(20,{"charttype","bar";"color1", "blue";"max",100})
```

It will take common "word" colors, for more precision use hexadecimal (#0000FF).

I hope this helps.

Comment: excellent, thanks. will add that if you want a dynamic color (based on the progress), there's nothing built-in - but you can use an if-else chain to choose a color string

Comment: Don't work for me with comas, I use this one instead:  `=SPARKLINE(E43; {"charttype"\"bar";"max"\30;"color1"\"blue"})`

Answer (score 9):

You can use this quick and dirty (yet powerful) workaround: you build up a function that repeats N times (with REPT function) the char" | " (or whatever you like), where N is you percentage ratio.
In the formula below N is

`=REPT(CHAR(406);N)`

**EDIT**, even better: just replace `actualValues` and `\D32` with your values (can be a range) and maximum and it'll show the progress bar inside the cell.

`=SPARKLINE(actualPercentage;{"charttype"\"bar";"max"\D32})`

This is a tiny preview:
[Progress Bar using Gsheet sparkline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aY3no.png)

For reference check [the google docs support page for sparkline](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093289?hl=en)

Comment: Did this stop working? I'm trying to reproduce but nothing seems to work. My code is now: ```=SPARKLINE(G2:G3;{"charttype","bar";"max",100})```

Comment: =SPARKLINE(`cellwithValue`;{"charttype"\"bar";"max"\ `cellwithTotal`}) should work

Comment: It did! Seems like the problem was with the syntax, I should use this \ instead of a comma, like this: ```=SPARKLINE(F1;{"charttype"\"bar";"max"\ 1})``` Thanks a lot!